# Custom controls for embedded youtube player not showing on :hover in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I have a chromeless embedded youtube player set up with some custom controls. The controls are absolutely positioned in a div along with the iframe, like so, and are hidden until the user mouses over the video:

```
psuedo-code:
<div id="video">
   <youtube iframe, embedded via JavaScript>
   <div id="controls></div>
</div>
```

This is fine and dandy and works perfectly underneath Webkit and Gecko; mousing over the video counts as mousing over its containing element. In IE 9, this is not the case; the controls only show when explicitly moused over the video div and not the iframe.

What can I do? CSS solutions are best but I'll use Javascript if it's really necessary.

Comment: Just add a mouseover for the the iframe...

Comment: As said, it's not an ideal solution, but I tried a javascript mouseover on the iframe. The result? Once again works under Gecko and Webkit but not IE 9.